# Kindle App stopped working in Wine

Tags: wine, kindle

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and wine 1.6.2.

A while ago I installed the Kindle app in wine and have been using it happily ever since, by simply clicking on the shortcut on my desktop to start it.

However today I find that the Kindle shortcut now says "Kindle.lnk" and no longer works.

How can I fix this?

Thanks